# import method from current module

Tags: python, python-import

I would like to import a method in the same module where it is defined like this:

```
def method1():
    print('1')


def method2():
    print('2')


boolean = True
if boolean:
    from __file__?? import method1 as method
else:
    from __file__?? import method2 as method

method()
```

is this somehow possible?

and what if all this is inside a class:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        boolean = True
        if boolean:
            from MyClass?? import method1 as method
        else:
            from MyClass?? import method2 as method

        method()
    
    @staticmethod
    def method1():
        print('1')

    @staticmethod
    def method2():
        print('2')
```

is this somehow possible? or what is a workaround to achieve the same thing? I already tried using partial from functools but it slows down quite a bit

EDIT: many thanks for all your answers, I didn't know I could assign a method to a variable

Comment: Why are you using `import`? Just do `method = method1`

Comment: Not sure why you think `partial` has anything to do with importing (it does not) or why you think that you should `import` something if it is defined in the same file. Just use `self` before the method name, for example `self.method1()` (for the class example)

Comment: As per @mousetail, you just need `method = method1` or `self.method = self.method1`.

Comment: Why do you have to import it, if it is in same module

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments you do not need to import a method that is defined in the same file. So your solution would be to just:

```py
def method1():
    print('1')


def method2():
    print('2')


boolean = True
if boolean:
    method = method1
else:
    method = method2

method()
```

And for the class:

```py
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        boolean = True
        if boolean:
            self.method = self.method1
        else:
            self.method = self.method1

        method()
    
    @staticmethod
    def method1():
        print('1')

    @staticmethod
    def method2():
        print('2')
```